# Group overlapping rectangles from array as fast as possible

Tags: java, computer-vision

I was trying to make my own computer vision project. I decided to start with matching computer generated objects before I go in the real world. First tests went good, it's able to match an object and does recognise color properly. When searching for green square this is my result:

[image: image description]
<sup>I draw red frame on the location returned by my search function</sup>

However once the environment is more blurry, there are more possible matched locations. And there even might be more desired targets. This is a screenshot from a computer game:

[image: image description]
The searched object is in the red frame. I'm basing my search on similar colors, particularly on distance between average colors. This is what I get if I highlight all the search results from my test program:

[image: image description]

Obviously, there's ton of rectangles matched on the location where my objects are. I need to group them and then pick only one of them.

The question therefore is: How to group overlapping rectangles and separate every group in an array?

Answer (score -1):

In your image [image] you have a set of `N` rectangles that you draw in red, you need an algorithm that give you `k` representative rectangles and for this particular image `k` will be equal to 2.

The algorithm you need is something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis where the dataset you need to cluster is the set of the centers of the rectangles, that means that a cluster is represented by a 2D point which is the center of a representative rectangle.

A clustering algorithm can be for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering where you can choose `k` as explained here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set

Once you get `k` the algorithm will give you the `k` representative centers; then for each rectangle the algorithm will tell you to what cluster the rectangle belong. Then the representative rectangle can be computed in this way: the center of it is the cluster, the width is the mean width of all the rectangles belonging to the cluster, the height is the mean height of all the rectangle belonging to the cluster.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for posting this. While it can be used to solve my particular problem I would really prefer the strict mathematical grouping.